# Split string at second space after colon

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following string which I need to split at the space before the labels

```
RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6
```

Desired result

```
RATE: 3.00%
SPEED: 280
TOT. WT: 52172.6
```

The spaces in the labels are killing me. Can use use regex when splitting a string? Regex not being more forte, I'm struggling with an expression to tear this down.

**UPDATE**
Because I only grabbed a the first part of the string, I missed the fact that some values themselves had spaces:

```
RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6 ERROR: +0.0 (10) AVG: 3.07 DEVIATION: 6.10
```

Desired Result:

```
RATE: 3.00%
SPEED: 280
TOT. WT: 52172.6
ERROR: +0.0 (10)
AVG: 3.07
DEVIATION: 6.10
```

Thanks to @p.s.w.g for the solution. Can the matches from the Select-String be used to add members to an existing object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [positive lookbehind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion) (`(?<= … )`). For example:

```
> $str = 'RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6'
> $str -split '(?<=:\s*\S+)\s+'
RATE: 3.00%
SPEED: 280
TOT. WT: 52172.6
```

This will split the string on any space that is immediately preceded by a colon, zero or more whitespace characters, and one or non-whitespace characters.

Alternatively, you could use the [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) cmdlet for more structured processing, like this:

```
> Select-String '(?<key>[^\s:][^:]+):\s+(?<val>\S+)' -InputObject $str -AllMatches `
  | %{$_.Matches} `
  | Select-Object -Property @{n='key';e={$_.Groups['key']}}, `
                            @{n='val';e={$_.Groups['val']}}

key     val
---     ---
RATE    3.00%
SPEED   280
TOT. WT 52172.6
```

---

**Update** given your updated requirements, you'll need a more advanced regex:
This one uses a lookbehind *and* a lookahead (`(?= … )`).

```
> $str = 'RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6 ERROR: +0.0 (10) AVG: 3.07 DEVIATION: 6.10'
> $str -split '(?<=:\s*[\d.%() +-]+)\s+(?=[A-Z. ]+:)'
RATE: 3.00%
SPEED: 280
TOT. WT: 52172.6
ERROR: +0.0 (10)
AVG: 3.07
DEVIATION: 6.10
```

But having two lookarounds like this is pretty ugly. I would recommend something more like this:

```
Select-String '(?<key>[^\s:][^:]+):\s+(?<val>[\d.%() +-]+)' -InputObject $str -AllMatches `
  | %{$_.Matches} `
  | Select-Object -Property @{n='key';e={$_.Groups['key']}}, `
                            @{n='val';e={$_.Groups['val']}}
key       val                                                                   
---       ---                                                                   
RATE      3.00%                                                                 
SPEED     280                                                                   
TOT. WT   52172.6                                                               
ERROR     +0.0 (10)                                                             
AVG       3.07                                                                  
DEVIATION 6.10
```

Note that in both cases you may have to modify the `[\d.%() +-]` character class if the values may contain other characters I haven't included here.

Comment: Thanks! Your first example worked well for my needs but I should have posted the entire string. One of my values contains a space ERROR: +0.0 (10) and the (10) is being dropped from the 'data' and picked up on the next label (10) AVG.   String:RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6  ERROR: +0.0 (10) AVG: 3.07 DEVIATION: 6.10

Comment: @togatown See my updated answer. Also, please update your question with the full requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the "separating" space with a newline and then split at newlines:

```
$s = 'RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6 ERROR: +0.0 (10) AVG: 3.07 DEVIATION: 6.10'
$a = $s -replace '(.+?: [^a-z]+) ',"`$1`n" -split "`n"
```

Answer (score 0):

More verbose, but also more intuitive to read:

```
$string = 'RATE: 3.00% SPEED: 280 TOT. WT: 52172.6'

$string -match '(RATE:.+?)\s+(SPEED:.+?)\s+(TOT. WT:.+)\s*$' > $nul
$Matches[1..3]

RATE: 3.00%
SPEED: 280
TOT. WT: 52172.6
```

If you want an object:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property $(ConvertFrom-StringData  ($Matches[1..3] -replace ':','=' | Out-String)) |
      Select RATE,SPEED,'TOT. WT'

RATE  SPEED TOT. WT
----  ----- -------
3.00% 280   52172.6
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it but with two steps e.g. (this example with semi-colon)

```
$p=$suppliedapps.replace("; ",";")
$AppsArray=$p.split(";")
$appsarray
```